# Dropdown list is not show in primefaces datatable column filter box

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am using Jsf 2.2 and primefaces 4.0. when I use this code All is ok.

```
 <p:column headerText="Status" filterBy="#{List_request.rechargeStatusName}" filterMatchMode="contains" >

           <h:outputText value="#{List_request.rechargeStatusName}" />
 </p:column>
```

But When I try to load a Dropdown list in The filter box in this column.
And  write this code

```
 <p:column headerText="Status" filterBy="#{List_request.rechargeStatusName}" filterMatchMode="contains" >
                            <f:facet name="filter">
                                <p:selectOneMenu value="#{List_request.rechargeStatusName}" onchange="PF('reTab').filter()">
                                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="-Select One-" itemValue="#{null}" noSelectionOption="true" />
                                    <f:selectItems value="#{allRequestDetailsBean.rechargeStasusNameList}" />
                                </p:selectOneMenu>
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{List_request.rechargeStatusName}" />
            </p:column>
```

Then dropdown list is not show in filter box and  Filtering not working--------Plase help anybody .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filter facets are not supported in 4.0... (check the documentation, check the [blog](http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=3084) to see when it was added etc..)

Answer (score 1):

Since the *Filter Facets* is not available in 4.0 , you can use the `filterOptions` of the `<p:column`, just create an array of `SelectItem[]` , with the relevant values and place it in your `filterOptions`

example:

```
<p:column filterBy="#{car.manufacturer}"   
    headerText="Manufacturer" footerText="exact"  
    filterOptions="#{tableBean.manufacturerOptions}"  
    filterMatchMode="exact">  
    <h:outputText value="#{car.manufacturer}" />  
</p:column>


private SelectItem[] manufacturerOptions;
```

...

```
    manufacturers = new String[10];  
    manufacturers[0] = "Mercedes";  
    manufacturers[1] = "BMW";  
    manufacturers[2] = "Volvo";  
    manufacturers[3] = "Audi";  
    manufacturers[4] = "Renault";  
    manufacturers[5] = "Opel";  
    manufacturers[6] = "Volkswagen";  
    manufacturers[7] = "Chrysler";  
    manufacturers[8] = "Ferrari";  
    manufacturers[9] = "Ford"; 

public SelectItem[] getManufacturerOptions() {  
    return manufacturerOptions;  
}
```

See full example on the showcase [DataTable - Filtering](http://primefaces-rocks.appspot.com/ui/datatableFiltering.jsf)

---

[Read more in the docs](http://file:///C:/Users/daniel.COMMUNITAKE/Downloads/primefaces_users_guide_4_0_edtn2.pdf)

Comment: Thanks Daniel . It Works . But Which since  version is available  Filter Facets Please Inform me. Thank again

Comment: Probably since PF-5, ( according to the following http://blog.primefaces.org/?p=3084 )

Comment: Since PF-5 is available Filter Facets  .Thanks Deniel